# Mule- Parsing all child node of a particular element from a Soap Envelope

Tags: soap, mule

I have a SOAP request Envelope which looks something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tsh="http://mulesoft.org/tshirt-service">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tsh:AuthenticationHeader>
         <apiKey>?</apiKey>
      </tsh:AuthenticationHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tsh:OrderTshirt>
         <size>xxl</size>
         <email>abcd.@dfg.com</email>
         <name>xyz</name>
         <address1>aaaa</address1>
         <address2>asdf</address2>
         <city>werty</city>
         <stateOrProvince>sdd</stateOrProvince>
         <postalCode>111111</postalCode>
         <country>India</country>
      </tsh:OrderTshirt>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now here, I need to parse all the child elements of `<tsh:OrderTshirt>` i.e. after parsing the output should be something like this :

```
<tsh:OrderTshirt>
         <size>xxl</size>
         <email>abcd.@dfg.com</email>
         <name>xyz</name>
         <address1>aaaa</address1>
         <address2>asdf</address2>
         <city>werty</city>
         <stateOrProvince>sdd</stateOrProvince>
         <postalCode>111111</postalCode>
         <country>India</country>
      </tsh:OrderTshirt>
```

I've idea for parsing one element by declaring namespaces in Mule's namespace manager. (referred [reading soap header element in payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201528/reading-soap-header-element-in-payload)).

Not sure about how to parse a node with it's child elements.

Please share your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit what you are trying to achieve.
The body needs to be send to a SOAP webservice?

Or you want to extract the values?

Easily possible with DataWeave, and no extra namespace declarations needed in the code.

The XML will be your payload and you can refer to the body with:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
payload.Envelope.Body
```

However it will output an additional XML header on top.

Have a look here how to remove it:

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/51394/remove-xml-definition-from-dataweave-output.html

Otherwise use namespace declarations and use Set Payload and as value use an Xpath expression that refers to the body of the XML so that becomes the payload.